# Обращение ко всем пустым полям MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим, есть таблица в которой 25 полей, 16 из них имеют пустое значение. Как обработать средствами php все поля с пустым значением, чтобы задать им одно и тоже значение, например, нет информации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     while(list($key,$value) = each($row)) {
        if(empty($value)) {
            $row[$key] = 'Пустое значение';
        }
     }
     $data[] = $row;
}
```

както так...

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    foreach ($result as $v){
       if ($v=='') {
           echo "Нет информации";
       } else {    
           echo $v; //Поле с данными
       }    
    }
}
```

Но минус в том, что поля будут выводится в том порядке, в каком идут они в таблице базы.

Comment: ну тут не суть собственено :)<br>
Важно понимать что полюбому надо проходится по результатам выборки в цикле...

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ISNULL(field, 'нет информации') FROM table

Comment: Тоже вариант, возможно иногда лучший, только вот досада - надо перечислять все поля ^^<br>
Правда если процедурой написать то нестрашно, но опять таки - поменялась структура таблицы - переписывай структуру, а проходу в цикле по барабану как называются поля и сколько их вообще...

Comment: можно этот запрос оформить как VIEW

Comment: А чем это принцепильно будет отличатся от процедуры?<br>
Абсолютно ничем, я уже писал выше что если поменяется структура таблицы то есть вероятность что прийдется переписывать запрос вьюшки...<br>
В цикле же таких проблем нету, хотя для истинных извратов теоретически можно напистаь цикл и в SQL процедуре, но быстрее чем php это всеравно работать не будет...

Answer (score 0):

А может есть смысл сделать это средствами MySQL - что быстрее на мой взгляд

Comment: Не люблю этого словосочетания, но вот это действительно экономия на спичках

Comment: Да согласен- экономия на спичках) Но стараюсь все что касается формирования выборки с БД по максимуму выводить уже обработтаные данные

Comment: Та не вопрос, я вообще последнее время практически для всех операций с MySQL пишу процедурами, но по факту - мне так просто удобнее, выигрываю я лишь в том что на 100% обезопасен от SQL иньекций...
В скорости то не выигрываю по факту(правда что касается скорости разработки всетаки выигрываю :D)<br>
Но смысла в данном случае ИМХО нет никакого...<br>
По поводу скорости - это не быстрее ;)